# マクロでOneDriveに入っているファイルを開けたい

Tags: vba, excel

会社でOneDriveを使用しており、そこに入っているフォルダの中のワードファイルを開き（参照）して、エクセルの指定セルの文字を置換し、別のワードファイルに保存するというマクロを作成中です。

自分のデスクトップのフォルダでは成功しますが、OneDriveに格納すると下記のところで、エラー52が表示されます。

```
Set wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & buf)
```

pathはOneDriveのURL（https:・・・・）を読み取っており、グーグルで調べるとhttpsが原因であるという記事は見つけました。また、ローカルアドレスに変更もしたくなく・・・あくまでも職場で共有できるOneDriveに入っているワードファイルを開ける方法を探しております。無理であれば、OneDriveに格納して自分のデスクトップにDLして使用する形にしようと思っています。どうか宜しくお願いします。

Comment: もしかしたらこんな記事が何か参考になるかもしれませんね。[\[VBA\]OneDriveで同期しているファイルまたはフォルダのURLをローカルパスに変換する関数](https://kuroihako.com/vba/onedriveurltolocalpath/), [【ex24】OneDrive内のパスをVBAで参照](https://it-yobi.com/excel-b-noex24/)

Comment: 「ローカルアドレスに変更したくない」理由はなぜでしょうか？恐らく通常の `Documents.Open` では URL 形式でのファイルは開けないので、OneDrive だからが原因では無さそうです。素直にローカルアドレスでパスを指定するか、いったん URL 指定でダウンロードしてから開くことになりそうです。

Comment: こちらの記事も関連してそうな感じなので参考になるかもしれません。[VBAでOneDriveに保存してあるファイルのパスが「https://d.docs.live.net/」になって困った時の解決法はコレだ](https://tsurutoro.com/vba-trouble/#gsc.tab=0), [これで解決！！OneDriveに保存したVBAファイルのパスがURLになった時の柔軟な解決法](https://tsurutoro.com/vba-trouble2/#gsc.tab=0), [Windows 10でエラーになるマクロ](http://officetanaka.net/Excel/vba/tips/tips203.htm), [\[Excel\]\[VBA\] OneDrive 下に置いたブックの Path がおかしくなる不具合とその対策](https://gist.github.com/furyutei/20902048fe029c169aa29db9ae23f603), [Excel VBA「ThisWorkbook.Path」でエラーを回避する方法](https://scodebank.com/?p=696)

Comment: BingAIで聞いてみたらこちらの記事 [Open a file on OneDrive using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58533843/9014308) と類似の方法でExcelではなくWordに変えても出来るらしい回答がありました。その後にVisibleプロパティをtrueに設定していますが。ただしこちらの記事 [Empty Excel file when opening it from OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72012537/9014308) では同等の手順を行っても上手くいっていないという質問になっているのでどちらになるかは分かりません。まあ試してみてください。

Comment: よく見たら提示された1行は問題が発覚した箇所であって、冒頭で説明された手順を全て表している訳ではありませんね。関係するExcelファイルやExcel/Wordファイルの内容/処理についても記述して、可能ならば他の人がそのまま試せるようにしてみてください。

Comment: @kunif有難うございます！！ワンドライブは自分のPCと同期してないんです。以前同期したら、上手く同期しないファイルがあったり、デスクトップに大量のファイルが表示されたりしたので解除しちゃいました。また私以外にも使用するマクロなので、同期してるひと・してない人など様々おりまして・・・。教えて頂いたサイト<https://tsurutoro.com/vba-trouble/#gsc.tab=0>　を試してみようと思います！　ワードファイルが会社の書類の為、全て開示して質問できず申し訳ありません。今度はサンプルファイル・すべてのコードを開示して質問したいと思います。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: @cubic 有難うございます。ローカルパスにしたくない理由は、色んなPCと共有するマクロだからです。そもそもopenはURL形式でのファイルは開けない・・・そこを知りつつももがいてました。申し訳ありません。デスクトップにDLしてローカルアドレスを指定すると使用できるのですが、その手間を省きたく試行錯誤してました。。。

Comment: もしかしたらこの記事 [Get URL for file stored in OneDrive with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72100364/9014308) とか言及されているツールのリポジトリ [cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FileTools) が参考になるかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

恐らくは (PCごとに) ログインユーザー名が異なる際にファイルパスも変わってしまうため、パスを一意に指定する方法が分からずに URL 指定を使おうとしているのだと思われます。

以下の様に `%OneDrive%` などの環境変数を使えば、OneDrive のパスに展開されるので、複数の環境でも使いまわすことが出来ると思います。

**例:**

```
%OneDrive%\ファイル.docx
```

| 環境変数名 | 説明 |
| --- | --- |
| `OneDriveCommercial` | 組織アカウントのOneDriveフォルダのルートパス |
| `OneDriveConsumer` | 個人アカウントのOneDeiveフォルダのルートパス |
| `OneDrive` | `OneDriveCommercial` と同様 |

**参考:**
[Windows10 OneDriveのパスを取得する方法](https://itmemo123.net/windows/387/)
[OneDriveの環境変数を活用する](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/win10tips-360/)

Comment: %USERPROFILE%直下にあるとも、OneDriveという名前であるとも限らないので、こういう指定はNGです

Comment: @suzukis OneDrive のルートフォルダを指す環境変数があるようなので、回答を更新しました。

Answer (score 0):

OneDriveのGraphAPIを使用してファイルのアップロード、ダウンロードをするツールがあります。
同期を考えなくていいのならば、補助として使えるのでは？
[Graph OneDrive](https://github.com/dariobauer/graph-onedrive)というツールですが、Pythonが必要です

Answer (score -1):

OneDriveをローカルコンピューターに同期してください：
　その後、VBAマクロでファイルパスを変更してください。
　例えば、

```
Set wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\あなたのユーザネーム\OneDrive\あなたのフォルダー\対象ファイル名.docx")
```

ご確認ください。

Comment: Ariyama会社の色んな方と共有して使用するため同期が難しく、、、。ご回答有難うございます。